# Can update page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a div element which is populated by the query result(in index.php). I have also another file widget.php which has same query to update page. I have variable in widget.php "page" which navigates through the pages. If I use widget.php?page=2 it will load next page with results. I want to update a div element in index.php on click.(Click "next" and show another 8 news without reloading page).

in index.php :

```
<button type="button" id="prevbutton">Previous</button>
<button type="button" id="nextbutton">Next</button>

<div id="list"></div>
```

in script.js:

```
$("#prevbutton, #nextbutton").click(function () {

    var id_name = $(this).attr('id');
    var page = 0;

    if (id_name == '#prevbutton' || id_name == '#nextbutton') {
            if (id_name == '#prevbutton') {
                page -= 1;    
            }
            if (id_name == '#nextbutton') {
                page +=1;
            }    
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'widget.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: "page=" + page,
            success: function (data) {
                //called when successful
                $("#list").html(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //called when there is an error
                //console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

in widget.php :

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=60");
include("logindb.php");
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = $page*9;
?>
                <div id="list">
                    <?php
                    $abfrage59 = "SELECT n.news_title,n.news_id,FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, n.timestamp, NOW())) as diff
                    FROM news n
                    WHERE n.domain_id = '2' AND n.timestamp < NOW()
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                    LIMIT $page,9";
                    $ergebnis59 = mysql_query($abfrage59);
                    while ($row59 = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis59)) {

                    $newstitleslug = $row59->news_title;
                    $newstitleslug = str_replace(' ', '-', $newstitleslug);
                    $newstitleslug = strtolower($newstitleslug);

                    echo "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4\" style=\"padding-bottom: 15px;\">
                            <div class=\"item\">
                                <img class=\"main\" src=\"http://www.example.com/news/$row59->news_id.png\" />
                                <div class=\"text\">
                                    <div class=\"inner\">
                                        <a href=\"http://www.example.com/$newstitleslug/$row59->news_id/\" style=\"color:white;\">$row59->news_title<br />
                                        <span class=\"date\">$row59->diff hours ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";

                    }
                    ?>
<?php
include("close_connect.php");
?>
```

So I want to update value $page on click and refresh content of DIV with new data. Thanks in advance.

Edit: removed script from script.js and put in the end of the index.php body:

```
<script>

    $("#prevbutton, #nextbutton").click(function () {

            var id_name = $(this).attr('id');
            var temppage = 1;

            if (id_name == 'prevbutton' || id_name == 'nextbutton') {
                    if (id_name == 'prevbutton') {
                        temppage -= 1;    
                    }
                    if (id_name == 'nextbutton') {
                        temppage +=1;
                    }
                var page = temppage;
                }


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'widgets/news_archive_widget.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: "page=" + page,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //called when successful
                        $("#list").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        //called when there is an error
                        //console.log(e.message);
                    }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: With every click on next button I want to load next 9 results, but nothing happens.

Comment: What does the complete `widget.php` file look like? You have only posted 2 lines that don't do anything...

Comment: @jeroen updated `widget.php`

Comment: You probably want  'var page' outside the scope of the click handler function. Otherwise everytime the buttons are clicked it will be '0' and you either add or subtract 1 from it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#` you're prefixing to `prevButton` and `nextButton` as `$(this).attr('id')` will return the id without the `#`. The value of id_name will either be `prevButton` or `nextButton`.

UPDATE:
Your final js script should look like this:

```
$("#prevbutton, #nextbutton").click(function () {

 var id_name = $(this).attr('id');
 var page = $("#currPageNumber").val();

 if (id_name == 'prevbutton' || id_name == 'nextbutton') {
    if (id_name == 'prevbutton') {
        page -= 1;    
    }
    if (id_name == 'nextbutton') {
        page +=1;
    }    
 }

 $.ajax({
    url: 'widget.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: "page=" + page,
    success: function (data) {
        //called when successful
        $("#list").html(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
 });
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=60");
include("logindb.php");
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = $page*9;
?>
<div id="list">
    <?php
        $abfrage59 = "SELECT n.news_title,n.news_id,FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, n.timestamp, NOW())) as diff
        FROM news n
        WHERE n.domain_id = '2' AND n.timestamp < NOW()
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT $page,9";
        $ergebnis59 = mysql_query($abfrage59);
        while ($row59 = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis59)) {

        $newstitleslug = $row59->news_title;
        $newstitleslug = str_replace(' ', '-', $newstitleslug);
        $newstitleslug = strtolower($newstitleslug);

        echo "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4\" style=\"padding-bottom: 15px;\">
                <div class=\"item\">
                    <img class=\"main\" src=\"http://www.example.com/news/$row59->news_id.png\" />
                    <div class=\"text\">
                        <div class=\"inner\">
                            <a href=\"http://www.example.com/$newstitleslug/$row59->news_id/\" style=\"color:white;\">$row59->news_title<br />
                            <span class=\"date\">$row59->diff hours ago</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type='hidden' value='".$_GET['page']."' id='currPageNumber'>
                </div>
            </div>";

        }
    ?>
<?php
include("close_connect.php");
?>
```

Comment: You are true, but it still did not fix the problem.

Comment: Like @Hoyen pointed out, the location of var page = 0; should be outside the handler. As it is now, the page number will always be set to 0 each time one of the buttons is clicked.

Also ensure your `widget.php` script is in the same dir with the js file.

Comment: I used `var page = 0;`outside of `$("#prevbutton, #nextbutton").click(function () {});` Still nothing

Comment: You should set the page number somewhere in the DOM (updating it each time a new page is loaded) and get the value when you want to load a new page.

Comment: For example, you can have a hidden input field inside your `widget.php` script like `<input type='hidden' value="$_GET['page']" id="currPageNumber">`. 

So inside your click handler, you can get it this way `var page = $("#currPageNumber").val();`

Comment: I pasted script to news.php and it started responding. Just when I click on next it increments just once and stop. When I click next again nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: @Sagi No idea unless I see a snippet of `news.php`.

Comment: I updated post. I just moved script to index and in worked, but button moves only one page. BUt I think problem is that script is stuck on if statements.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but remove the `<div id='list'>` in the `widget.php` script because when a page is loaded, the id `list` will be duplicated on the page.

Comment: I got what is the problem. I set `page = 5;`. When I lick next it increases to 6 and returns 6th page. When again clicking it again increases `page=5` by 1. It does not remember previous choice. Any idea how to force it remember?

Comment: Add this to your `widget.php` script.

`<input type='hidden' value="$_GET['page']" id="currPageNumber">` and get the current page like this `var page = $("#currPageNumber").val();`

Comment: thanks for a help. I was not able to do the way you explained and tried another that worked.